# Why rails String to DateTime conversion ignores timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone, parameters

I have a request with params:

```
...&from_date=2015-07-09T11:28:06.763+02:00
```

In controller when using `params[:from_date]` it returns DateTime object:

```
Thu, 09 Jul 2015 11:28:06 +0000
```

it is an UTC time but original timezone (+02:00) is not taken into account in conversion. Further the app timezone is set to timezone 'Warsaw' (+2:00).

How can I make rails recognize the timezone in `params[:from_date]`?

EDIT.

I have changed parameter type:

```
optional :from_date, type: DateTime, desc: "From date"
```

to
    optional :from_date, type: String, desc: "From date"

And have found that rails converts '+' to space so I get "2015-07-09T11:28:06.763 02:00". So the problem is found.

Comment: When I try this out I get: `"2015-07-09T11:28:06.763+02:00".to_datetime  #=> Thu, 09 Jul 2015 11:28:06 +0200`. How are you using the `params[:from_date` value?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I get good time just ignoring timezone. It is not a regular controller but grape api method.

Comment: I use binding.pry at the begining of method and then just put 'params[:from_date]' command in console. Then I get the exact time and date as in parameter but timezone is +0000 so it is essentially different then input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
params[:from_date].to_datetime.in_time_zone('Warsaw')
```

Comment: params[:from_date] has already a DateTime class. Further it has wrong value - doesnt account for timezone in request parametr. Method 'in_time_zone("Warsaw") just converts this wrong value to different timezone